# how to stop saving data in associated tables in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.2

i have a table(user table) which is associated to many tables. While saving data, it is getting saved in all associated table. But in some scenario i need to save only in base table (User) not in assoicatied table.

In cakephp 2 we have option callback => false, but how can we achive this in cake php 3?

Answer (score 0):

You may specify the associated tables in which you want to save (cf: [CakePHP ORM Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-data-to-the-join-table)).

You could then do :

```
$this->Users->save($user, ['associated' => false]);
```

To disable the save in associated tables. (I have not tested as I'm at work, I will edit my message if it does not work for me !)

Answer (score 0):

following code worked for me

$entity = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data, ['ignoreCallbacks' => true,'associated' => []]);

$result = $this->Users->save($entity);